# ASP.NET Identity or ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have a brand new MVC5 project and I need user management. When I create a new project, Visual Studio goes through and adds a significant amount of code for me so that I can utilize the concept of authentication and authorization.

Question: Is ASP.NET Identity a "good" solution for user management outside of a web application? I would like to one day add a mobile application to the mix and I would like the same BLL codebase to be used for the web application and the mobile app.

Also, my very limited understanding of ASP.NET Identity is that it uses `HttpContext` behind the scenes to  "wire up" the authentication and authorization. As such, I can use attributes on my controller actions such as `[Authorize]` to inherit the authorization behavior. I really like this feature but I'm concerned that this approach won't work with mobile apps necessarily because `HttpContext` is not being used.

One thing to note here is that I also do not like that I have the `IdentityConfig.cs` class inside of my MVC project using `DBContext` directly. I have been fiddling  with using an n-tier approach but I cannot seem to successfully break away the auth/auth portion into a proper BLL/DAL architecture model.

So, I guess I have two questions in all:

1. Is ASP.NET Identity a "good" auth/auth choice for both web & mobile apps
2. If "yes", how can I tear out the `RoleManager`/`UserManager` classes to a BLL and have them pull utilize a Data Access Layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, by all means go for ASP.Net Identity 2 authentication if you are planning to build mobile apps later. Check out [this post](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources) to learn more about ASP.Net Identity 2.

I ended up using ASP.Net identity 2 OAuth authentication for my webapi project that's also designed to cater to mobile apps. There is no need to worry about Httpcontext. All that you need to keep track of in the client side (be it a web app or mobile app) is the access_token issued by OAuth.

2) Yes. ASP.Net Identity 2 is extremely flexible in that it even allows you to use another DB engine such as MySQL to store user/roles information. [Check this out](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/implementing-a-custom-mysql-aspnet-identity-storage-provider). I put all the customized OWIN specific tables in a different BLL and plugged that into the WebAPI project. Both are linked via interfaces because the DAL resides in a different project. Combine it with a great DI framework such as StructureMap/Ninject/SimpleInjector and you won't have to worry about DbContext messing up with your architecture model.